# Sequence flow of questions

Tags: discussion

In one of my questions, I filled in too much of my thoughts and that made that question's throw completely unfocused. (Yet still then I thank people who answered that question).

I think that now I can phrase the question in a better manner, maybe in a more conveying manner. So, if I edit the question again would it be charted again for invitations to answer?

I feel that if I ask a series of Questions one after one, in a sequential manner, then I may converge to what I need. Is this practice encouraged on Stack Overflow?

Comment: RE the last part - No. The idea is that you ask a good question in the first place.

Comment: Editing your question bumps it up at the [SO active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/active) page. There's a number of people lurking there.

Answer (score -1):

So long as the question isn't closed, it doesn't *stop* being open for answers.  That a question has been answered doesn't stop anyone else from posting an answer, if they think they can post a better one.

By all means, edit the question if you think you can make it a lot clearer.

You should not be posting a new question just to post a less noisy version of a question you've previously asked.  You should only be asking a new question if you have a new question, rather than an improved phrasing of an existing question.

Comment: What about the sequence of questions ?

Comment: @AgniveshSingh Like I said in my answer, if you have improvements to your question so that it can be better understood, you should be editing your question, not asking new questions.